# Dynamic JSON creation using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to JSON and tried the below example to see the results but it returns an empty array in the console. Any suggestions?

```js
function createJSON() {
  var obj = [];
  var elems = $("input[class=email]");
  
  for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
    var id = this.getAttribute('title');
    var email = this.value;
    tmp = {
      'title': id,
      'email': email
    };
    obj.push(tmp);
  }
  
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);
  console.log(jsonString);
}

createJSON();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Change `$("input[class=email]")` into `$('input[class="email"]')`. You need to add quotes for attributes values in a selector. And since it's a class, you can use `$('input.email')`.

Comment: @Gil not quite accurate. The quotes around attribute values in a selector are only required if the value contains a space. In this case `[class="email"]` and `[class=email]` will both work - although `.email` would be far more performant and better practice.

Comment: changed but still getting this output in console [] , its empty

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is because you're mixing plain JS and jQuery methods. For example, you shouldn't iterate through a jQuery object with a `for` loop, and a jQuery object doesn't have a `getAttribute()` method. You would use `each()` and `attr()` or `prop()` in those cases, respectively.

That said, you can more simply create an array from a jQuery object containing a collection of elements using `map()`, something like this:

```js
function createJSON() {
  let arr = $('.email').map((i, el) => ({
    title: el.title,
    email: el.value
  })).get();
  return JSON.stringify(arr);
}

let json = createJSON();
console.log(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="email" class="email" title="email_1" value="foo@foo.com" />
<input type="email" class="email" title="email_2" value="bar@bar.com" />
```

Comment: var  networkgroup_obj="GRP1";    var NetworkObjectUUID1="ABC"; var NetworkObjectUUID2="XYZ";  I am trying to create for a json dynamic function for this but bit not clear how to???? [{
    "name": "networkgroup_obj1",
    "objects": [
        {
            "type": "Host",
            "id": "NetworkObjectUUID1"
        },
        {
            "type": "Host",
            "id": "HostObjectUUID2"
        }}

Comment: That's a much more complex nested structure than your question states. I would suggest you start a new question about that, making sure to include all the relevant HTML along with an ***accurate*** example of the output you want to create.

Comment: Thank you very much, i found a way to get complete string , i just add that fix prefix to json output using php string append function and it worked , anyway  its not a a very effienct way to do, but it solved the problem for now.